# MySQL: Retrieve result from table3 based on values in table2 tagged to table1

Tags: mysql

table5: managers

```
id | name
1 | Steve
2 | Jacob
```

table4: deputy_managers

```
id | manager_id | name
1 | 2 | Mary
2 | 2 | Linda
3 | 1 | Nathan
```

table3: team_leads

```
id | deputy_manager_id | name
1 | 3 | Stephen
2 | 1 | Patrick
3 | 2 | Tony
4 | 1 | Austin
```

table2: sales_executives

```
id | team_lead_id | name
1 | 1 | Johnny
2 | 3 | Dalton
3 | 4 | Sonora
4 | 2 | Jessie
```

table1: sales

```
id | sales_executive_id | product | quantity
1 | 3 | product1 | 10
2 | 2 | product3 | 6
3 | 3 | product2 | 5
4 | 1 | product1 | 4
```

With the data available in the sales table, I wanted to write mysql query to fetch total quantity of a product sold:

1. From manager Steve's team.
2. From deputy manager Mary's team.
3. From team lead Tony's team.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. From manager Steve's team

   ```
   SELECT   product, SUM(quantity)
   FROM     managers         m
       JOIN deputy_managers  d ON d.manager_id         = m.id
       JOIN team_leads       t ON t.deputy_manager_id  = d.id
       JOIN sales_executives e ON e.team_lead_id       = t.id
       JOIN sales            s ON s.sales_executive_id = e.id
   WHERE    m.name = 'Steve'
   GROUP BY product
   ```
2. From deputy manager Mary's team

   ```
   SELECT   product, SUM(quantity)
   FROM     deputy_managers  d
       JOIN team_leads       t ON t.deputy_manager_id  = d.id
       JOIN sales_executives e ON e.team_lead_id       = t.id
       JOIN sales            s ON s.sales_executive_id = e.id
   WHERE    d.name = 'Mary'
   GROUP BY product
   ```
3. From team lead Tony's team

   ```
   SELECT   product, SUM(quantity)
   FROM     team_leads       t
       JOIN sales_executives e ON e.team_lead_id       = t.id
       JOIN sales            s ON s.sales_executive_id = e.id
   WHERE    t.name = 'Tony'
   GROUP BY product
   ```

See them on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bcc8/1).

Comment: eggyal, that works perfect! Thank you so much! It took tonnes of pressure off me. Thanks again!!